# Basic Authentication in Spring MVC 3.1

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, basic-authentication, restful-authentication

I am trying to develop a sample application using Spring MVC 3.1 and REST API.

There is a login form to authenticate user before entering into the application. I want to use REST API for  basic authentication using the credentials (username and password) provided by the user in the login form.

My problem is that I don’t know how can I use REST API for basic authentication purposes.

I have searched a lot but did not get any right tutorial from where I can I resolve my error.

Please can anybody guide me or tell me any good article ?

Now I am taking help of the following tutorials 
http://www.jpalace.org/docs/technotes/spring/rest-security.html but getting null pointer exception.

**RestClient.java**

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;


public class RestClient {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    static final String URL = "http://www.assembla.com/spaces/my_spaces";
    static final String username = "aaaaa";
    static final String password = "aaaaa";

    public RestClient() {

        BasicSecureSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new BasicSecureSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setCredentialsProvider(new SimpleCredentialsProvider(
                new Credentials(username, password)));
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    }

    public void exec() {
        System.out.println("restTemplate :::::::::::::::::: " + restTemplate);
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(URL, String.class);
        System.out.println("Response:::::::::::::: " + response);
    }

}
```

**BasicSecureSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java**

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
  import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;


    public class BasicSecureSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory extends
            SecureSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {

        public BasicSecureSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory() {
        }

        protected void prepareSecureConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) {
            if (credentialsProvider == null) {
                return;
            }
            Credentials credentials = credentialsProvider.getCredentials(null);
            String token = credentials.getUsername() + ":"
                    + credentials.getPassword();
            BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
            String encodedAuthorization = enc.encode(token.getBytes());
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "
                    + encodedAuthorization);
        }
    }
```

**SecureSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory .java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;

import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory;

abstract public class SecureSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory extends
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {

    protected CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;

    public SecureSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    }

    public CredentialsProvider getCredentialsProvider() {
        return credentialsProvider;
    }

    public void setCredentialsProvider(CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider) {
        this.credentialsProvider = credentialsProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientHttpRequest createRequest(URI uri, HttpMethod httpMethod)
            throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = openConnection(uri.toURL(), null);
        prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod.name());
        prepareSecureConnection(connection);
        return new SecureSimpleClientHttpRequest(connection);
    }

    abstract protected void prepareSecureConnection(HttpURLConnection connection);

}
```

**SecureSimpleClientHttpRequest .java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
public class SecureSimpleClientHttpRequest implements ClientHttpRequest {
    public SecureSimpleClientHttpRequest(HttpURLConnection connection) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public HttpMethod getMethod() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public URI getURI() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public OutputStream getBody() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse execute() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

**SimpleCredentialsProvider .java**

```
public class SimpleCredentialsProvider implements CredentialsProvider {

    private Credentials credentials;

    public SimpleCredentialsProvider(Credentials credentials) {
        super();
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    @Override
    public Credentials getCredentials(String str) {

        return credentials;
    }

}
```

**CredentialsProvider .java**

```
public interface CredentialsProvider {

    public Credentials getCredentials(String str);
}
```

**Credentials.java**

```
public class Credentials {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Credentials(String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

I am getting following error:

> Oct 16, 2012 12:56:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$AcceptHeaderRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:530)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:444)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:409)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:207)

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be, if your already using spring MVC, to use it in combination with Spring Security: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity.html

Since it supports basic authentication in various ways:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-form-and-basic

Also have a look at this article to get an idea of using it together with REST:
http://www.baeldung.com/2011/11/20/basic-and-digest-authentication-for-a-restful-service-with-spring-security-3-1/

Comment: I am trying to help from following URL "http://www.jpalace.org/docs/technotes/spring/rest-security.html" But not getting success.